# How I can calculate a product based on in or out?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel with multiple sheets, 2 of the sheets are an inventory and a in, out tracking.

this is an example of inventory
[image]

and this is an example of in and out
[image]

lets take as example the product name [cablu conductor], and I want to calculate based on IESIRI (means OUT) how many they are out. I tried with VLOOKUP and SUMIF to try search the name and the type of the operation, out or in, and calculate them in inventory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS works if i correctly understand what you want to do. For illustration i've made an example within one spreadsheet.

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11,G2,$C$2:$C$11,"IESIRI")
```

[image: How I can calculate a product based on in or out?]